# Is nutzen etymologically related to English “to use”?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, english

Is the German verb “nutzen” etymologically related to the English verb “to use”? Before looking into it a little bit, I had guessed that they were related via a rebracketing thing, but then I learned that “to use” seems to come from Latin, not from the Germanic things. So, is the similar sound of “nutzen” and “use” just a coincidence?

Comment: Also I'm voting to close this question, because the etymology can be looked up anywhere: [nutzen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nutzen) [use](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/use#Etymology).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short answer:

The two words do not sound similar and they have very different etymologies.

---

#### In detail:

###### pronunciation

As the user infinitezero already pointed out in [his comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/71953/is-nutzen-etymologically-related-to-english-to-use#comment172123_71953), there is no sound that the two words have in common (although [[ʊ]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-close_near-back_rounded_vowel) and [[u]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_back_rounded_vowel) sound similar). The [s] in the voiceless alveolar sibilant affricate [t͡s] (pronounced like "ts" in "cats", "tsar" and "tsunami") will not be recognized as an s-sound (compare the pronunciation of the names *Betsy* = [ˈbɛt͡si] and *Bessy* = [ˈbɛsi]:

- nutzen = [ˈnʊt͡sn̩]
- use = [juːs] or [juːz]

###### Etymology of "nutzen"

The modern German verb *"nutzen"* and the German noun *"Nutzen"* are closely related and have the same etymological root. The noun was *"nuz"* in Middle and Old High German. In about the 9th century there existed even two versions of this word: *"nuz"* and *"nuzza"* that both had the same meaning. Before that there existed the Proto Germanic noun *"nutōną"*.

From this Proto Germanic noun *"nutōną"* also evolved Old English *"notian"* (to make use of something) and *"nytt"* (the use) and Middle English *"nutte"* (pronunciation: like "noot") which obviousely became extinct and is no longer in use in modern English.

###### Etymology of "use"

This word was imported into Middle English (as "use") from Old French (where it was "us") between the 12th and 14th century. Old French is one of the direct successors of Latin, so the root of the Old French *"us"* was a Latin word. It was *"usus"* (meaning *"benefit"* and *"usage"*). The ancestor of this Latin word was the Proto Italic word *"oissos".*

Comment: As infinitezero remarked, use is pronounced [juːz], the last consonant being voiced.

Comment: @Rha: Both pronunciations are correct: [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/use#Pronunciation), although I believe to hear more often a voiceless s. I edited my answer and added the second version.

Comment: The verb *use* has /z/, /s/ is the noun.

Comment: The root of "usus" is the verb "utor" (to use, to make use of, to have, ...) and "usus" is the PPP of it. The change in the root consonant (here: t->s) is common in latin verbs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess I was indeed reading to much into things. Dang human pattern-seeking.

Comment: This answer does nothing to falsify a probable relation of \*nuton to *utor*. At best, it gives a false impression of certainty. For reference, *putzen* and Latin *puto* are comparable for obvious reasons (voiced b must be assimilated in Frankonian, cp. *Abbutze* [apud Mundstuhl]). Die rekonstruierten Wurzeln PIE \*newd-, bzw. \*h₃eyt- für den lateinischen Stamm sind wiederverwertbar, sprich: gehören zum Altpapier. Darauf kann die Antwort nicht beruhen.

Comment: Die einschlägige Wurzel für "consume, enjoy" ist \*h₂ew-, was sich vorallem in *ausnutzen* niederschlägt, ebenso "die Milch ist aus" (*verbraucht*, nicht *außer Haus*, nicht *out of fashion*, sondern \*awez > *over*, cp. "past overdue", chiefly of food, cp. *mildew*, s. a. \*wes-, vgl. *verwesen*). N ist vielfältig erklärbar. An individueller Unfähigkeit dürfte es insofern nicht scheitern. Spasseshalber: \*n-(h₁)n-h₂w-h₂ew-, was übrigens *neu* (\*new-) als *ungenutzt* dahinstehen ließe.

Comment: @vectory: Was genau hält dich davon ab, eine bessere Antwort als meine zu schreiben? Das wäre ein positiver Beitrag von dem alle was hätten.

Comment: (...) ist der gravierende Fehler, dass kein HD *Utzen* vorliegt, offensichtlich (s. aber *alte Otze*, ggf. *Uotze*, Altnordisch *futh*, usw. usf.)